# Rubygems: Rubyzip required version >= 1.9.2 update on CentOS 6.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, tarantula

When I do:

```
/usr/bin/gem -v 
1.8.25
```

when I do:

```
gem -v 
2.6.11
```

I have installed rubygems 2.4.0 via rvm . Also I have installed rubygems-1.8.25-1.el6.R.noarch.rpm via yum.

but when I install tarantula it gives me an error:

> Gem::InstallError: rubyzip requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
>   An error occurred while installing rubyzip (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install rubyzip -v '1.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.

Then I type: `gem install rubyzip` and the latest version of ruby zip got installed manually.

Comment: so, what is your question ?

Comment: You need to make sure that the `rvm` installed ruby is the standard one. What does `ruby -v` return?

Comment: My Question is How I can install tarantula or How can I install rubyzip without upgrading Rubygems or How can I upgrade on rubygems on my CentOS i686 arch machine???

Comment: ruby -v: 
Output: ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [i686-linux]

Comment: ruby -v
Output: ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [i686-linux]

gem -v
Output: 2.6.11

/usr/bin/ruby -v
Output: ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i386-linux]

/usr/bin/gem -v
Output: 1.8.25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by installing rvm then use this command to set rvm systemwide.

Installation Steps:

- curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable --rails cd
- /usr/local/rvm/archives/
- tar -zxvf rvm-
- cd rvm-
- ./install
- source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh

Configure RVM:

- rvm use